# Excel split everything between characters

Tags: excel

I have a column with the following data

**Komponenten** > Finishing Kit > **Sättel**

**Komponenten** > Schaltung & Antrieb > Kettenschaltungen > **Schaltwerke**

**Zubehör** > Training & Leistung > Heimtrainer & Rollentrainer > **Heimtrainer & Rollentrainer Ersatzteile & Zubehör**

I want to keep the text before the first > and keep the entry after the last > (I've bolded the examples above)

This is tricky because some examples have 3 > and some have 4 >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using formulas, you can get the first item this way:

```
=LEFT(A1, SEARCH(">",A1,1)-1)
```

and the last item this way:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(">",A1,SEARCH(">",A1,1)+1))
```

where the string you are looking at is in A1.

Credit: [Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-functions-49ec57f9-3d5a-44b2-82da-50dded6e4a68)

Answer (score 0):

First Item:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,">",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

Last Item:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,">",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```